# Firestore query subcollection and parent document

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some trouble with the docs of firestore and their best practices in order to query subcollections and the parent document. I trying to query inside my firebase function with Typescript.

The DB:

├── User (Collection)
│   └── User (Document with ID)
│   │   └── Plan (Subcollection)

I have a list of user IDs in a array which I need to collect information from
the user document and from the subcollections plan the current document.

```
.where("id", in, idArray).get()
```

But how tho get the Data from the User document and the subcollection (Plan) document (current)
I don't know the most efficient way to query in the scenario and the documentation
is not really clear for me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Firestore Document Structures? It's not clear where the array is.

Comment: @Dharmaraj the array has nothing to do with the firestore itself. It contains only the ids of the wanted user docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firestore query can only consider the information in the documents that it'll return. A query on the `Plan` subcollection has no way to access/query on information in the `User` documents.

So if you want to select plans for a set of users, you'll need to **include the ID of the user document into each plan document** too. This sort of duplication is quite common when working with NoSQL databases, and is one of the reasons Firestore can meet its performance guarantees.